# How to search saved gps coordinates on a rout from source to destination on google map?

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to develop website that shows all the major landmarks on a rout from source to destination using google map.

I have saved those major landmarks GPS coordinates in my database.

But, I do not know how can I search my saved GPS coordinates and find out which of them are on the rout shown by google map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may create a polyline from the path of the route(may be e.g. retrieved via [`route.overview_path`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#DirectionsRoute)) and then use the method [`google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#poly) of the [geometry-library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry) to check the landmark-coordinates against the polyline.

Comment: Thanks Dr. Molle. This is definitly one option. I will try this.

Comment: I found one more way to achieve this. But I have not tried this solution yet. While looking for all possible way in google example code I found this link - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/demogallery  - in this link look for "RouteBoxer". How many ppl here have tried this open-source-library? Please share your experience.